# How to create dataframe in R of available redshift clusters using aws cli

Tags: r, amazon-redshift, aws-cli

I would like to use the `aws cli` to create a dataframe in R that contains each of the available redshift clusters that I have, output example below:

```
cluster_identifier
my-cluster-1
my-cluster-1
```

The command: `system(intern = TRUE, "aws redshift describe-clusters")` brings back a whole list of information about each cluster, but I don't know how to restrict this json output to bring back just the cluster_identifier, and secondly how to then read it into an R dataframe in a usable format

I tried wrapping the above system command with `fromJSON` but this returned the error:

```
Error in fromJSON(system(intern = TRUE, paste0("aws redshift describe-clusters"))) : 
  incomplete list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to answer my own question in the end, I used `--query` to restrict the output to just the cluster identifier I wanted, then could return it as a dataframe using `as.data.frame`

```
cluster_list <-
  as.data.frame(
    system(intern = TRUE,
           paste0(
             "aws redshift describe-clusters --output text --query 'Clusters[*].ClusterIdentifier'"
             )
           ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

setnames(cluster_list, "cluster_identifier")
```